# How to remove default response headers in website in case of AWS?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, security, netjson

When i send the request able to see the default AWS Header which seem to sensetive.
The following headers is reflecting.

```
X-Amzn-Requestid: <Value>
X-Amz-Apigw-Id: <Value>
X-Amzn-Remapped-Server: <Value>
X-Amzn-Remapped-Date: <Value>
```

is it possible to customize the header?

I came through some article but still i'm not sure about the resolution.